# Drawing Königsberg landscape showing the bridges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Just for fun, I was trying to draw the picture (which I found [here](http://www.math.ku.edu/~jhukle/105/52-56.ppt)):

[image]

However, I don't know how to create irregular shapes in `tikz`. Can anybody help?

Comment: Some ideas using `random decorations`: [decorating-with-random-steps-a-filling-pattern](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42003/decorating-with-random-steps-a-filling-pattern), [torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges/86401#86401)

Comment: By irregular you mean those "jagged" edges? Or you mean non-rectangular, non-ellipse shapes? For the first, the comment of Ignasi applies. For the second, you can use a path composed by a sequence of coordinates, joining them with -- and using "rounded corners", or you can use `plot coordinates` and a sequence of coordinates, using `smooth` option, or you can use `hooby` package which allows metapost syntax and results for a smooth curve passing throug a sequence of points.

Comment: @JLDiaz Thank you. I mean non-rectangular, non-ellipse shapes. I am working on it.

Comment: Have a look at control points and tension parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a possible reproduction of your figure.

[image]

I just scaled the image up, and manually traced coordinates (pixels) of the contours in Gimp, and then filled the necessary areas. The code is long, and it is not very nice. :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, calc}

\definecolor{land}{HTML}{95EA64}
\definecolor{water}{HTML}{BBE0E3}
\definecolor{bridge}{HTML}{FEFF9E}

\tikzset{%
    contour/.style={%
        very thick,%
        decoration={%
            random steps,%
            segment length=4pt,%
            amplitude=0.5pt%
        },%
        rounded corners=1pt,%
        decorate%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm, y=9.19cm]
    %\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    %   {\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=9.19cm]{OOeXi.png}};

    %water
    \filldraw[water] (0, 0) -- (0, 1) -- (1, 1) -- (1, 0) -- cycle;


    %bridge top 1
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.329, -0.300)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.423, -0.301)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.399, -0.399)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.328, -0.404)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.423, -0.301)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.399, -0.399)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.328, -0.404)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.329, -0.300)$);

    %bridge top 2
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.532, -0.302)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.558, -0.310)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.591, -0.338)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.609, -0.404)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.549, -0.388)$) --
        cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.591, -0.338)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.609, -0.404)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.532, -0.302)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.549, -0.388)$) ;


    %bridge top 3
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.635, -0.328)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.656, -0.304)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.669, -0.276)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.364)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.776, -0.396)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.762, -0.420)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.635, -0.328)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.762, -0.420)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.669, -0.276)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.364)$);

    %bridge middle right
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.658, -0.590)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.668, -0.546)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.778, -0.524)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.792, -0.554)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.590)$) --cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.668, -0.546)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.778, -0.524)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.658, -0.590)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.590)$);

    %bridge bottom 1
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.350, -0.826)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.410, -0.804)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.422, -0.794)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.412, -0.708)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.372, -0.702)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.336, -0.695)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.422, -0.794)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.412, -0.708)$)
    ($(0, 1) + (0.350, -0.826)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.336, -0.695)$);

    %bridge bottom 2
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.596, -0.700)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.535, -0.708)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.523, -0.784)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.535, -0.708)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.523, -0.784)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.596, -0.700)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$);

    %bridge bottom 3
    \filldraw[bridge] ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.660, -0.862)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.858, -0.717)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.837, -0.702)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.826, -0.688)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.785, -0.668)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.785, -0.668)$)
        ($(0, 1) + (0.660, -0.862)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.858, -0.717)$);


    %land top
    \filldraw[land] (0, 1) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0, -0.287)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.080, -0.287)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.161, -0.281)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.178, -0.273)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.257, -0.289)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.280, -0.287)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.329, -0.300)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.423, -0.301)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.532, -0.302)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.558, -0.310)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.591, -0.338)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.635, -0.328)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.656, -0.304)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.669, -0.276)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.720, -0.246)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.741, -0.233)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.780, -0.210)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.824, -0.206)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.874, -0.178)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.931, -0.169)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.969, -0.161)$) -- ($(1, 1) + (0, -0.149)$) --
        (1, 1) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0, -0.287)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.080, -0.287)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.161, -0.281)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.178, -0.273)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.257, -0.289)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.280, -0.287)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.329, -0.300)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.423, -0.301)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.532, -0.302)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.558, -0.310)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.591, -0.338)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.635, -0.328)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.656, -0.304)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.669, -0.276)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.720, -0.246)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.741, -0.233)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.780, -0.210)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.824, -0.206)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.874, -0.178)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.931, -0.169)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.969, -0.161)$) -- ($(1, 1) + (0, -0.149)$);


    %land bottom
    \filldraw[land] ($(0, 1) + (0, -0.890)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.067, -0.880)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.067, -0.880)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.085, -0.860)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.111, -0.858)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.139, -0.849)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.161, -0.860)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.212, -0.847)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.242, -0.830)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.350, -0.826)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.410, -0.804)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.422, -0.794)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.450, -0.784)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.523, -0.784)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.660, -0.862)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.672, -0.882)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.679, -0.924)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.698, -0.968)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.714, -0.990)$) --
        (0.718, 0) -- (0, 0) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0, -0.890)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.067, -0.880)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.067, -0.880)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.085, -0.860)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.111, -0.858)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.139, -0.849)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.161, -0.860)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.212, -0.847)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.242, -0.830)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.350, -0.826)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.410, -0.804)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.422, -0.794)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.450, -0.784)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.523, -0.784)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.581, -0.777)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.660, -0.862)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.672, -0.882)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.679, -0.924)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.698, -0.968)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.714, -0.990)$) --
        (0.718, 0);


    %land right
    \filldraw[land] (1, 0) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.978, -0.975)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.954, -0.908)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.921, -0.829)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.900, -0.810)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.880, -0.775)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.858, -0.717)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.837, -0.702)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.826, -0.688)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.785, -0.668)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.623)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.590)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.792, -0.554)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.778, -0.524)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.764, -0.466)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.762, -0.420)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.776, -0.396)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.364)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.838, -0.368)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.864, -0.380)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.910, -0.384)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.946, -0.392)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.971, -0.394)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (1, -0.414)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[contour] (1, 0) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.978, -0.975)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.954, -0.908)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.921, -0.829)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.900, -0.810)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.880, -0.775)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.858, -0.717)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.837, -0.702)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.826, -0.688)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.785, -0.668)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.623)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.590)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.792, -0.554)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.778, -0.524)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.764, -0.466)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.762, -0.420)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.776, -0.396)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.796, -0.364)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.838, -0.368)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.864, -0.380)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.910, -0.384)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.946, -0.392)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.971, -0.394)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (1, -0.414)$);


    %island
    \filldraw[land] ($(0, 1) + (0.241, -0.622)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.235, -0.587)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.240, -0.540)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.249, -0.524)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.252, -0.498)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.266, -0.482)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.271, -0.462)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.288, -0.454)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.300, -0.434)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.308, -0.418)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.320, -0.412)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.328, -0.404)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.399, -0.399)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.453, -0.393)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.518, -0.386)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.549, -0.388)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.609, -0.404)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.624, -0.410)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.644, -0.438)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.663, -0.486)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.670, -0.519)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.668, -0.546)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.658, -0.590)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.648, -0.612)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.636, -0.648)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.633, -0.666)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.617, -0.677)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.596, -0.700)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.535, -0.708)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.500, -0.709)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.457, -0.717)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.412, -0.708)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.372, -0.702)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.336, -0.695)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.291, -0.679)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.268, -0.652)$) --
        cycle;
    \draw[contour] ($(0, 1) + (0.241, -0.622)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.235, -0.587)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.240, -0.540)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.249, -0.524)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.252, -0.498)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.266, -0.482)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.271, -0.462)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.288, -0.454)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.300, -0.434)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.308, -0.418)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.320, -0.412)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.328, -0.404)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.399, -0.399)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.453, -0.393)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.518, -0.386)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.549, -0.388)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.609, -0.404)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.624, -0.410)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.644, -0.438)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.663, -0.486)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.670, -0.519)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.668, -0.546)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.658, -0.590)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.648, -0.612)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.636, -0.648)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.633, -0.666)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.617, -0.677)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.596, -0.700)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.535, -0.708)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.500, -0.709)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.457, -0.717)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.412, -0.708)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.372, -0.702)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.336, -0.695)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.291, -0.679)$) -- ($(0, 1) + (0.268, -0.652)$) --
        ($(0, 1) + (0.241, -0.622)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW! Just great! I was (in a way) working on it, but much worse than your's.

Comment: How much time did you waste? :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul About an hour and a half. :)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind not having an exact reproduction, it is possible to get the gist of the required image fairly simply:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,topaths}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{sketch/.style={decorate,
 decoration={random steps, amplitude=1pt, segment length=5pt}, 
 line join=round, draw=black!80, very thick, fill=#1
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\clip [preaction={fill=cyan!10}] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);

\foreach \p/\r/\w/\h in 
  {(3,1)/5/1/4, (3,9)/-5/1/-4, (5,1)/-5/0.75/4, (5,9)/5/0.75/-4, 
  (5,5)/-90/0.75/4, (5,1)/-50/1/4, (6,8)/50/0.75/-4}
\draw [sketch=yellow!25]
   [shift={\p}, rotate=\r] rectangle +(\w,\h);

\draw [sketch=green!50]
  (-1,-1) -- (-1,0) to [bend left, looseness=0.5] (6,2) to [bend left] (7,-1) 
  (11,-1) to [bend left] (8,6) to [bend left] (11,6) -- cycle
  (-1,9) to [bend right, looseness=0.5] (7,8) to [bend left] 
  (11,9) -- (11,11) -- (-1,11) -- cycle
  (2,4) to [bend left, looseness=0.5] (2.5,6) to [bend left] 
  (6,6) to [bend left] (6,3.5) to [bend left] (2,4) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Challenge accetped!

**Start: 01:22 o'clock**

...

**First Milestome: 01:30 o'clock**

Traced it using Portrace and having a svg file now

Original:

[image: Original]

SVG:

[image: SVG]

Sure the tracing can be optimised...justr aiming for speed.

**Next step: Seaching a svg2tikz converter...**

**Update: 01:46 o'clock**

Found [How to convert an SVG image with LaTeX in Inkscape, to PNG?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98594/how-to-convert-an-svg-image-with-latex-in-inkscape-to-png) (svg2tikz)

**End: 01:59 o'clock**

```
   LaTeX code too large too be posted (received an error message here)
```

I put the code here:

https://github.com/manuelkuehner/tex.stackexchange.com/blob/master/2014-06-09_01

Here are the first lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cf7f899}{RGB}{247,248,153}
\definecolor{cb9dee1}{RGB}{185,222,225}
\definecolor{c90aba4}{RGB}{144,171,164}
\definecolor{c93e862}{RGB}{147,232,98}
\definecolor{c8ee760}{RGB}{142,231,96}
\definecolor{c9ca86a}{RGB}{156,168,106}
\definecolor{c79c956}{RGB}{121,201,86}
\definecolor{c78948a}{RGB}{120,148,138}
\definecolor{c6b9e58}{RGB}{107,158,88}
\definecolor{c586d50}{RGB}{88,109,80}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(0.06625,0)}]% g2995
  % path3015
  \path[fill=cf7f899] (0.0000,148.0000) -- (0.0000,0.0000) -- (161.0000,0.0000) --
    (322.0000,0.0000) -- (322.0000,148.0000) -- (322.0000,296.0000) --
    (161.0000,296.0000) -- (0.0000,296.0000) -- (0.0000,148.0000) -- cycle;

  % path3013
  \path[fill=cb9dee1] (0.0000,148.0000) -- (0.0000,0.0000) -- (161.0000,0.0000) --
    (322.0000,0.0000) -- (322.0000,148.0000) -- (322.0000,296.0000) --
    (161.0000,296.0000) -- (0.0000,296.0000) -- (0.0000,148.0000) --
    cycle(216.5000,247.0000) .. controls (219.2500,244.8117) and
    (221.8897,243.0165) .. (222.3660,243.0106) .. controls (222.8423,243.0046) and
    (225.4437,241.3765) .. (228.1468,239.3922) .. controls (230.8499,237.4079) and
    (235.4102,234.9010) .. (238.2808,233.8213) .. controls (241.1514,232.7416) and
    (248.4500,228.5664) .. (254.5000,224.5430) .. controls (260.5500,220.5197) and
    (266.9625,216.4900) .. (268.7500,215.5882) .. controls (270.5375,214.6865) and
    (272.0000,213.4879) .. (272.0000,212.9247) .. controls (272.0000,212.3616) and
    (270.4756,210.3313) .. (268.6125,208.4129) .. controls (265.1773,204.8757) and
    (260.7332,203.0000) .. (255.7880,203.0000) .. controls (254.2891,203.0000) and
    (242.6651,208.1750) .. (229.9570,214.5000) .. controls (217.0891,220.9045) and
    (205.6141,226.0000) .. (204.0590,226.0000) .. controls (201.0839,226.0000) and
    (191.0000,229.8125) .. (191.0000,230.9373) .. controls (191.0000,231.9585) and
```

TikZ output:

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

How it is done in Inkscape:

[image]

[image]

Not using `Export to Clipboard` lead to an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1415, in <module>

    main_inkscape()

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1403, in main_inkscape

    effect.affect()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\extensions\inkex.py", line 216, in affect

    if output: self.output()

  File "tikz_export.py", line 1346, in output

    f = codecs.open(self.options.outputfile, 'w', 'utf8')

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\python\Lib\codecs.py", line 870, in open

    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Test'
```

I had to sign in to Github in order to download the files from https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz. Then I put the files from the `extensions` and the `inkexlib` folder directly to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\extensions`. Some of them were already there.

**Last words:**

The answer was down voted. Don't know why...thought it was a "just for fun" question.

Comment: Inkscape can export to TikZ...

Comment: Thanks. I see. Don't know where to find iz in Inkscape yet. In the extensions there is no tikz entry. At least I don't see it.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Inkscape can export directly to TikZ after you install the following extension: [inkscape2tikz](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). Make sure you restart Inkscape after you installed the extension.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner You should post the tex code somewhere- may be at github.

Comment: OK. I will do it later.

Comment: Done! I updated the answer and added the link https://github.com/manuelkuehner/tex.stackexchange.com/blob/master/2014-06-09_01

Comment: Thank you very much for all my heart.