# Tikz custom dotted pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I have no idea for reducing distance of dots (lines) in tikz dotted (horizontal lines) pattern. 
I find some similar examples in this website (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54358/108724)), but it was so complicated. Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Could you please list the codes that you found and explain why you do not like them? Otherwise there is a danger you will get the same answer again.

Comment: For example see this one:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42003/decorating-with-random-steps-a-filling-pattern  or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how this is directly related to your question. This post discusses a random pattern of solid lines, doesn't it? And please add the relevant information to your question, and not in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mydots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{2pt}{2pt}}% original definition: \pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}
{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}%
  \pgfusepath{fill}%
}%

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mynewdots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}% original definition: \pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}
{%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}%
  \pgfusepath{fill}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=dots] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
\draw[pattern=mydots] (4,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
\draw[pattern=mynewdots] (8,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  And what about line case? Do i allowed to use this patteren without referencing in literatures?

Comment: @C.F.G what does IT mean?

Comment: IT? Information Technology?! :)   . my means is copyright issues.

Comment: @C.F.G You can use this code as you want. But, if it solves your problem, you could accept the answer ;-)